# Recover from failed Ceph Cluster - Inactive PGs (Down)

Tags: ceph

### Ceph Cluster PGs inactive/down.

I had a healthy cluster and tried adding a new node using ceph-deploy tool. I didn't put enable noout flag before adding node to cluster.

So while using ceph-deploy tool, I ended up deleting new OSD nodes couple of times and it looks like Ceph tries to balance PGs and now those PGs are inactive/down state.

I tried recovering one PG just to see if it recover but that's not the case. I am using ceph to manage OpenStack glance images and VMs. So now all new VMs and existing VMs are slow or not responding.

Current Output of Ceph tree: (Note fre201 is new node. I have recently disabled OSD services on that node)

`[root@fre201 ceph]# ceph osd tree
ID  CLASS WEIGHT   TYPE NAME       STATUS REWEIGHT PRI-AFF
 -1       70.92137 root default
 -2        5.45549     host fre101
  0   hdd  1.81850         osd.0       up  1.00000 1.00000
  1   hdd  1.81850         osd.1       up  1.00000 1.00000
  2   hdd  1.81850         osd.2       up  1.00000 1.00000
 -9        5.45549     host fre103
  3   hdd  1.81850         osd.3       up  1.00000 1.00000
  4   hdd  1.81850         osd.4       up  1.00000 1.00000
  5   hdd  1.81850         osd.5       up  1.00000 1.00000
 -3        5.45549     host fre105
  6   hdd  1.81850         osd.6       up  1.00000 1.00000
  7   hdd  1.81850         osd.7       up  1.00000 1.00000
  8   hdd  1.81850         osd.8       up  1.00000 1.00000
 -4        5.45549     host fre107
  9   hdd  1.81850         osd.9       up  1.00000 1.00000
 10   hdd  1.81850         osd.10      up  1.00000 1.00000
 11   hdd  1.81850         osd.11      up  1.00000 1.00000
 -5        5.45549     host fre109
 12   hdd  1.81850         osd.12      up  1.00000 1.00000
 13   hdd  1.81850         osd.13      up  1.00000 1.00000
 14   hdd  1.81850         osd.14      up  1.00000 1.00000
 -6        5.45549     host fre111
 15   hdd  1.81850         osd.15      up  1.00000 1.00000
 16   hdd  1.81850         osd.16      up  1.00000 1.00000
 17   hdd  1.81850         osd.17      up  0.79999 1.00000
 -7        5.45549     host fre113
 18   hdd  1.81850         osd.18      up  1.00000 1.00000
 19   hdd  1.81850         osd.19      up  1.00000 1.00000
 20   hdd  1.81850         osd.20      up  1.00000 1.00000
 -8        5.45549     host fre115
 21   hdd  1.81850         osd.21      up  1.00000 1.00000
 22   hdd  1.81850         osd.22      up  1.00000 1.00000
 23   hdd  1.81850         osd.23      up  1.00000 1.00000
-10        5.45549     host fre117
 24   hdd  1.81850         osd.24      up  1.00000 1.00000
 25   hdd  1.81850         osd.25      up  1.00000 1.00000
 26   hdd  1.81850         osd.26      up  1.00000 1.00000
-11        5.45549     host fre119
 27   hdd  1.81850         osd.27      up  1.00000 1.00000
 28   hdd  1.81850         osd.28      up  1.00000 1.00000
 29   hdd  1.81850         osd.29      up  1.00000 1.00000
-12        5.45549     host fre121
 30   hdd  1.81850         osd.30      up  1.00000 1.00000
 31   hdd  1.81850         osd.31      up  1.00000 1.00000
 32   hdd  1.81850         osd.32      up  1.00000 1.00000
-13        5.45549     host fre123
 33   hdd  1.81850         osd.33      up  1.00000 1.00000
 34   hdd  1.81850         osd.34      up  1.00000 1.00000
 35   hdd  1.81850         osd.35      up  1.00000 1.00000
-27        5.45549     host fre201
 36   hdd  1.81850         osd.36    down        0 1.00000
 37   hdd  1.81850         osd.37    down        0 1.00000
 38   hdd  1.81850         osd.38    down        0 1.00000`

### Current Ceph Health:

Current Health of Ceph cluster

`~ceph -s 
cluster:
id:     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
health: HEALTH_ERR
        3 pools have many more objects per pg than average
        358887/12390692 objects misplaced (2.896%)
        2 scrub errors
        9677 PGs pending on creation
        Reduced data availability: 7125 pgs inactive, 6185 pgs down, 2 pgs peering, 2709 pgs stale
        Possible data damage: 2 pgs inconsistent
        Degraded data redundancy: 193505/12390692 objects degraded (1.562%), 351 pgs degraded, 1303 pgs undersized
        53882 slow requests are blocked > 32 sec
        4082 stuck requests are blocked > 4096 sec
        too many PGs per OSD (2969 > max 200)
services:
mon: 3 daemons, quorum ceph-mon01,ceph-mon02,ceph-mon03
mgr: ceph-mon03(active), standbys: ceph-mon01, ceph-mon02
osd: 39 osds: 36 up, 36 in; 51 remapped pgs
rgw: 1 daemon active
data:
pools:   18 pools, 54656 pgs
objects: 6050k objects, 10940 GB
usage:   21721 GB used, 45314 GB / 67035 GB avail
pgs:     13.036% pgs not active
            193505/12390692 objects degraded (1.562%)
            358887/12390692 objects misplaced (2.896%)
            46177 active+clean
            5070  down
            1114  stale+down
            1088  stale+active+undersized
            547   activating
            201   stale+active+undersized+degraded
            173   stale+activating
            96    activating+degraded
            61    stale+active+clean
            43    activating+remapped
            39    stale+activating+degraded
            24    stale+activating+remapped
            9     activating+undersized+degraded+remapped
            4     stale+activating+undersized+degraded+remapped
            2     active+clean+inconsistent
            1     stale+activating+degraded+remapped
            1     stale+remapped+peering
            1     active+undersized
            1     stale+peering
            1     stale+active+clean+remapped
            1     down+remapped
            1     stale+remapped
            1     activating+degraded+remapped
io:
client:   967 kB/s rd, 1225 kB/s wr, 29 op/s rd, 30 op/s wr`

I am not sure how to recover 7125 PGs which are present on active OSDs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: iops are also almost 0. Probably that's why its not recovering.

Answer (score 1):

In `luminous` release of ceph. Release is enforcing maximum number of PGs as 200. In my case they were more than 3000+ so I need to set max_number_of pgs parameter in `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf` file of monitor and OSDs as `5000` which enabled ceph recovery.